How do I retarget the LFS references of a local cloned git repository?
On my server I have LFS objects stored together in /data/lfs and the git bare repos stored in /data/repos/. These are remnants from a broken gitea install that I'm working to repair. As such all of the urls used to normally access these repos are unavailable. In the meantime, I'm in the process of migrating these repositories and I planned on doing that by pushing the bare repos directly to the new server. To do this, I'm following the instructions laid out in this stack overlow answer.
I succeeded in cloning the repo locally
$ git clone --mirror /data/repos/old_repo /data/repos/migration
Cloning into bare repository '/data/repos/migration'...
done.

Because these repos use git lfs, I also needed to fetch the lfs files before I could push. So I setup the repo to utilize the file:/// protocol since after cloning the repo using a local directory the git lfs Endpoint was configured without a protocol.
$ git lfs env
git-lfs/2.13.2 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.15.9)
git version 2.30.2

Endpoint=/data/repos/old_repo/info/lfs (auth=none)
LocalWorkingDir=
LocalGitDir=/data/repos/migration
LocalGitStorageDir=/data/repos/migration
LocalMediaDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/lib/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"

$ git remote set-url origin file:///data/repos/old_repo/

$ git lfs env
git-lfs/2.13.2 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.15.9)
git version 2.30.2

Endpoint=file:///data/repos/old_repo/ (auth=none)
LocalWorkingDir=
LocalGitDir=/data/repos/migration
LocalGitStorageDir=/data/repos/migration
LocalMediaDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/lib/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"


Once the Endpoint is configured correctly, I do:
$ git lfs fetch --all 
fetch: 174 object(s) found, done.
fetch: Fetching all references...
error transferring "b3558472ed74e6826d47f8c819af62409f321f9816a57d3b5d8f7184ca55bc4a": [0] remote missing object b3558472ed74e6826d47f8c819af62409f321f9816a57d3b5d8f7184ca55bc4a
error transferring "dd2ef8a60f635aebc6e8fe14b544a6171b9b14d6dd7204398bf93aaa7c1c1d3d": [0] remote missing object dd2ef8a60f635aebc6e8fe14b544a6171b9b14d6dd7204398bf93aaa7c1c1d3d
error transferring "811638be9a46622f039f9906c241819809c94b72a6d369e62d6b6925dcf981c0": [0] remote missing object 811638be9a46622f039f9906c241819809c94b72a6d369e62d6b6925dcf981c0
...
error transferring "ead2ce1d3786163460506516b75896dca0f305ba459f118cd2574d10553abb88": [0] remote missing object ead2ce1d3786163460506516b75896dca0f305ba459f118cd2574d10553abb88
error transferring "a8d0bac4ad9d9dbeb7c4cf7bfec2e63d3a6a6a32d0a8ec1642772264587d4261": [0] remote missing object a8d0bac4ad9d9dbeb7c4cf7bfec2e63d3a6a6a32d0a8ec1642772264587d4261
error transferring "bf1818e09545394557b74856a47b1194be9fcd38d9335d37cf7f20210fa9e33b": [0] remote missing object bf1818e09545394557b74856a47b1194be9fcd38d9335d37cf7f20210fa9e33b
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'file:///data/repos/old_repo/'

Thinking that maybe the Endpoint needed to be set to the directory where LFS objects were actually stored, I also tried doing that.
$ git remote set-url origin file:///data/lfs/

$ git lfs env
git-lfs/2.13.2 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.15.9)
git version 2.30.2

Endpoint=file:///data/lfs (auth=none)
LocalWorkingDir=
LocalGitDir=/data/repos/migration
LocalGitStorageDir=/data/repos/migration
LocalMediaDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=/data/repos/migration/lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/lib/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"

However, this still did not allow me to fetch the lfs files:
$ git lfs fetch --all
fetch: 174 object(s) found, done.
fetch: Fetching all references...
EOFnloading LFS objects: 100% (174/174), 456 MB | 0 B/s
EOF
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'file:///data/lfs'

I've also tried setting some config keys such as lfs.storage and lfs.url but neither of these seem to work, resulting in the same behaviour as documented above. I know there must be a way to re-link these lfs files but I haven't been able to find anyone working within my constraints: bare local repositories with git lfs that used to be managed by gitlab.
How might I relink these lfs files so that I may push my bare repos?
